# ASP.NET MVC 5 ModelState.IsValid with json input code

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with a `Test` class in my model and a `ModelTest` function in my controller.

I would like to be able to use `ModelState.IsValid` when I call the action using AJAX, so passing a JSON object. I tried this

```
public JsonResult Modeltest(Test input) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        return Json(new { Response = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(new { Response = "Error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The `Test` class is pretty straightforward

```
public class Test {
    public int num { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And the call will be something like this `http://myServer/myController/ModelTest?input={"num":5, "name ":"myName"}`

Of course it doesn't works and if I put a breakpoint at the first line in the server the `input` object is NULL. Is no only possible solution pass a JSON string, deserializing it and manually fill a model object? Isn't there a faster (and automated) way to parse the input as the specified class?

Comment: You should be doing this instead: `http://myServer/myController/ModelTest?num=5&name=myName` show your ajax call aswell

Comment: If you POSTed your JSON then it would work.  Not from within the query string like that though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
http://myServer/myController/ModelTest?input={"num":5, "name ":"myName"}
```

Is a *very* invalid URL.  Query strings are great for simple key/value pairs, for example:

```
http://myServer/myController/ModelTest?num=5&name=myName
```

In fact, for a simple object like your `Test` class, the model binder should be smart enough to interpret these values into an instance of that object.  (I'll be very surprised if it doesn't.)

However, if you have a JSON structure (which you may need for more complex objects) then that structure would have to go in the POST body rather than in the query string.

Comment: In answer to your question, yes MVC is smart enough to bind the query string values to the model like you have stated

Comment: Thank you! Another question, shouldn't `POST` be used to insert things and `GET` to get things? What if I need to pass a complex serialized object from client but just to request content and not to insert?

Comment: @Naigel: Generally, yes.  `GET` is strictly for observing state and not for changing it.  There are semantic arguments to be made for `POST`, though.  And the W3C spec leaves room for interpretation (intentionally).  A significant difference between the two is that `GET` has no request body.  So if you need to have a request body, `POST` is going to be your option.  `POST` is *generally* for creating resources.  But there's room for interpretation with operations like complex searches.  If it helps, semantically think of it as "creating a set of search results".

Answer (score 1):

If you `POST` your values using AJAX or using a form, it will automatically bind your JSON values to your incoming model in your action method.

Here's an example of jQuery code that you could use to post your JSON:

```
$.post("http://myServer/myController/ModelTest", {"num":5, "name ":"myName"}, function(e) {

    // Success
});
```